# "Arclength" parameterization of a surface

Tags: manifolds, parametric

Given an arbitrary parameterization of a differentiable curve $r: R\rightarrow R^n$ in terms of some variable $t$, we can re-parameterize (although perhaps not in closed-form)  $r$ in terms of its arclength $s$.  This gives a handy representation where as $s$ increases by 1, we move 1 unit along $r$ in $R^n$.

Is is 1) possible and 2) comparably straightforward to do this for surfaces?  I.e. if $r: R^m \rightarrow R^n$ is differentiable can we reparameterize $r$ so that moving 1 unit in $R^m$ moves us 1 unit along the surface $r$ in $R^n$?

Comment: I like to think of the Gauss map of an analogue of "arclength reparametrization" for a surface.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No, this latter would mean that any manifold is locally isometric to an Euclidean space with its flat metric. This is only true in dimension $1$ by the mean of arclength parametrization as you pointed out, the first obstruction coming to my mind being the [curvature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curvature).

Comment: The quantity of things that don't generalize neatly from 1-D to n-D causes me no end of amazement, delight and frustration.

Comment: I agree that the delight part is strong here: the article http://images.math.cnrs.fr/Un-theoreme-et-une-part-de-pizza (in french) explains curvature and how the fundamental theorem dealing with it helps us to properly eat pizzas.

Comment: This is infinitely more clear after having read the pizza article.  :)

Comment: Glad to hear that! :)