# Does the Uniformization Theorem for Riemann Surfaces allow us to show existence of an Arc Length Parametrization?

Tags: complex-analysis, differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

It's well known that arc-length parametrizations of curves do not generalize nicely to surfaces due to problems with curvature.

I'm trying to find a way to make it work nonetheless.

Now I have recently learned of the [Uniformization Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniformization_theorem) whereby any riemann surface can be conformally mapped to either the riemann sphere, complex plane, or the unit disk.

So I wanted to ask the following question. Given an orientable surface $S$ which uniformizes to $A$ which is either the plane, sphere. Can we then then describe a map $m: A \rightarrow S$ such that every curve $\gamma \subset A$ parametrized by $\tau$ results in an arc length parametrization of $m(\gamma(\tau)) \subset S$?

In plain terms, "moving along curves in A for constant distance with A's natural metric (geodesic distance) results in moving along curves in S for the same constant distance with S's natural metric"

Now I know some previous askers have been interested in this namely: ["Arclength" parameterization of a surface](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2976408/arclength-parameterization-of-a-surface)

where the idea of a Gauss Map was mentioned but it wasn't clear to me if a Gauss map meets the criteria I listed above.

NOTE: I dropped the unit disk and associated surfaces because distance on the unit disk isn't measure via geodesic distance but instead involves the hyperbolic distance and I just don't want to overcomplicate the question at this stage.

Comment: What do you mean by "the hyperbolic distance isn't measured via geodesic distance"? It distance is geodesic.

Comment: In the hyperbolic plane sure. But as a unit disk which lives in $\mathbb{R}^2$ we have to use a modified distance function from the usual Euclidean one.

Comment: I don't get your comment. Of course the distance isn't measure by the euclidean distance. Same thing for the sphere: its distance isn't euclidean

Comment: In the sphere there is a geodesic distance we can still use. In the open disk in $\mathbb{R}^2$ the geodesic distance IS the euclidean distance, which is what we don't want since it makes asking my question a lot more complicated.

Comment: Are you asking whether every simply-connected Riemann surface uniformized by the plane admits a metric isometric to the Euclidean plane, and similarly for the round sphere...? <> If it matters, the Euclidean metric on the open unit disk is incomplete, and therefore not a good way to think of "metrization/uniformization."

Comment: yes thats what im asking, and the reason i dropped the unit disk is for primitive reasons but i think the concern you have is related to my original concern with the unit disk.

Comment: You still did not ask a meaningful question: The word 'surface' can mean many different things,  a Riemann surface, a Riemannian surface, etc. What you are asking 8n the body if the question is different from what you said 'yes' to in a comment.

Comment: I think let’s pick Riemann Surfaces to start.